# Maven: Current project and dependent project use different version of the same library

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

The pom for my main project declares a version of hadoop-client. A dependency declares a *different* version of hadoop-client. Which one actually ends up being used?

pom.xml for my main project:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.apache.hadoop</groupId>
   <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.0</version>
   <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>*</groupId>
           <artifactId>*</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.myown.group</groupId>
   <artifactId>my-own-artifact</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>*</groupId>
           <artifactId>*</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

pom.xml for the library that my main project depends on:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.apache.hadoop</groupId>
       <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.0</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>*</groupId>
               <artifactId>*</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
```

Comment: mvn dependency:tree or :list will tell you.

Answer (score 3):

Maven has a complex set of rules for version resolution, summarized as 'nearest wins'. One source of details is [this post here.](http://techidiocy.com/maven-dependency-version-conflict-problem-and-resolution/) You can find out what Maven decided by using `mvn dependency:list` or `mvn dependency:tree`.